# Regexp for String_String?

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm pretty stupid to regexp but I have to use this... I have to validate a username field that must match to this scheme: "Firstname_Lastname"

This means that the valid username is only alphabet separated by an underscore. The first name and the last name must start with uppercase but the rest of them must be lowercase.

I have tried this but it's not working:

```
<?php
$username = "Dani_Sebi"; 

$regex = '/^[A-Z][a-z]+_^[A-Z][a-z]+/'; 

if (preg_match($regex, $username)) {

 echo $username . " is a valid username. We can accept it.";
} else {

 echo $username . " is an invalid username. Please try again.";
}
?>
```

Comment: A must read [article](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). On a side note, I hope you know what `^` means, it means `begin of string`. So throwing one `^` in the middle of your expression would ofcourse let it fail all time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` is misplaced inside the reex. Try this:

```
$regex = '/^([A-Z][a-z]+)_([A-Z][a-z]+)/';
```

Answer (score 2):

I bet this could be improved, but it works:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+_[A-Z][a-z]+$
```

Comment: `{1}` is redundant and could be removed.

Comment: Shorthand --> `/^[\w]+_[\w]+$/`

Comment: @matcarlson not sure that's true. Not a regex expert, but I think that also matches `lala_land` (all lowercase letters). OP states that first name and last name should always start with uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

`^[:upper:][:lower:]*_[:upper:][:lower:]*$`

There are single letter names as well, so this one is better.